# Auto scrolling to the top with active content snapping at a specific point

Tags: html, css

I'm thinking of creating an animation where the content auto scrolls to the top after every few secs and only the active one is highlighted with a bigger font.

The active content is snapped at a specific point and feels like z-index is higher whereas the inactive content is pushed to the back (feels like z-index is lower). I hope you got an idea of what I'm trying to convey.

The Image on the right side is associated with active content so automatically changes with the post.

Can someone help me figure out how to achieve this.

[image]